# Add items to array from several loops

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

The code provided below is an abstract of my real code. I want to add items from a number of arrays to a final array using multiple loops. But I also want to add the the same values multiple times, hence wrapping everything in another loop. It sounds messy but I think the code explains it well. Why am I only getting the results from one loop? In other words, why is `$total` only containing the six elements one-six and not 30 elements (one-six five times), as one would expect with the for loop?

```
for ($counter = 1; $counter < 5; $counter++) {
     $first_arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');
     $second_arr = array('four', 'five', 'six');

    $total = array();

    foreach ($first_arr as $x) {
        $total[] = $x;
    }

    foreach ($second_arr as $x) {
        $total[] = $x;
    }
}
var_dump($total);
```

Comment: If your example represents your actual use case insofar as `$first_arr`, `$second_arr` and `$total` having numerical keys, this can be done more cleanly and efficiently using `array_merge`, come to think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place following line outside for loop

```
 $total = array();
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you're resetting `$total` on each iteration of the outer loop. Declare it before the outer loop, and your problem will be solved.

Like so:

```
$total = array();
$first_arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$second_arr = array('four', 'five', 'six');

for ($counter = 1; $counter < 5; $counter++) {
    // assuming $first_arr and $second_arr have numerical keys
    // which they do, in this example
    $total = array_merge($total, $first_arr, $second_arr);
}

var_dump($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make few changes ....And it wil work

```
for ($counter = 1; $counter < 5; $counter++) {
 $first_arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');
 $second_arr = array('four', 'five', 'six');

$total = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($first_arr as $x) {
    $total[$i] = $x;
    $i++;
}

foreach ($second_arr as $x) {
    $total[$i] = $x;
    $i++;
}
}
var_dump($total);
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

thats because you have declaired the array within the loop. everytime the loop starts again, the array is resetted with null values and hence the final loop value is shown in  result.

declair these outside the loop and it will work fine,

```
$first_arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$second_arr = array('four', 'five', 'six');
    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= 5; $counter++) {
        foreach ($first_arr as $x) {
            $total[] = $x;
        }


        foreach ($second_arr as $x) {
            $total[] = $x;
        }
    }
```